# mysql database tables architecture

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have database having hundreds of tables with relations. I want to look a db design for understanding tables relations in a single place. Any idea how I can do this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try Phpmyadmin db diagram

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

or

MySQL Workbench:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Install `MySQL Workbench.`
And use this tool to see the database design & tables relations.